# All-JavaScript WhatsApp button

Tags: javascript, html, css, security, cross-browser

The following code creates a WhatsApp button.

How would you improve this code?

```js
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `
    <aside class="cbwtphone_wrapper">
        <img class="cbwtphone_icon" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6b/WhatsApp.svg/1024px-WhatsApp.svg.png"></img>
        <a class="cbwtphone_link" href="https://wa.me:NUMBER">
            <span class="cbwtphone_text">WhatsApp call</span>
        </a>
    </aside>
`)

newStyle = document.createElement("style");
newStyle.type = "text/css";
newStyle.innerHTML +=`
    .cbwtphone_wrapper {
        display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
        position: fixed;
        right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 2147483647;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 120%;
        font-weight: bold;
    background: linear-gradient(-160deg,#2494db 0%,#0d7ab8 78.66%) /* #149714; */
    }

    .cbwtphone_link {
        text-decoration: none; /* Fixes continuing line problem */
    }
    .cbwtphone_icon {
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    }
    .cbwtphone_text {
        vertical-align: middle;
    color: #fff;
    }
`;
document.head.appendChild(newStyle);
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't treat HTML as text strings in your code, because you won't get code completion or error detection in your IDE. Instead, for HTML you can use `createElement`

```
let mydiv = document.createElement("div")
mydiv.classList.add("cssrule")
mydiv.innerText = "Hello world"
document.body.appendChild(mydiv)
```

For CSS it's sadly not possible (as far as I know) to create new styles dynamically this way.

Comment: What makes you think OP is using an IDE?  You're right that manipulating DOM is more type-safe than injecting text representation, of course.

Comment: I don't think many developers code HTML / CSS without an IDE, but I could be wrong.